# use browsermobproxy when get the binarycontent How to do like fiddler utilDecodeResponse

Tags: python, selenium, fiddler, browsermob-proxy

I use python-browsermobproxy and python-selenium, then I set 'captureBinaryContent': True, so I can get the content, then I get the text from response, then use base64.b64decode to decode the response, the response is `'mimeType': 'application/protobuffer'`, but I can't use the decode text do use proto.ParseFromString, decode error.

I want to do like fiddler when getting the binarycontent using `sesstion.utilDecodeResponse`, then the body I want decode to proto. But when I use `python-browsermobproxy` and `python-selenium`, I don't know how to do it, I need some help.

code:

```
 for entry in proxy.har['log']['entries']:

    _url = entry['request']['url']

    _response = entry['response']

    _content = _response['content']
    #_content['mimeType'] is 'application/protobuffer'

    _text = _content['text']#get the text ,is base64

    text_dec = base64.b64decode(_text)
    
    '''
    how to decode the text_dec like fiddler utilDecodeResponse
    todo
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer,
when I check the request and response,I find the
{'name': 'content-encoding', 'value': 'br'}
the text is use br compress,so when I use brotli.decompress to decompress the text ,it is ok.
So you can check the content-encoding to select the decode func,like gzip br or other.

```
_url = entry['request']['url']

_response = entry['response']

_content = _response['content']
#_content['mimeType'] is 'application/protobuffer'

_text = _content['text']#get the text ,is base64

_text_dec = base64.b64decode(_text)

_really_data = brotli.decompress(_text_dec )
'''
then you can use _really_data ,like to decode in protobuf
'''
```